# What is the probability that exactly 3 people in a group of 7 have a birthday in the same month?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

### Question

> What is the probability that exactly 3 people in a group of 7 have a birthday in the same month, with no larger such group existing?

### Aprroach

Ignoring overcounting,

select $3$ from a group of $7$ and provide a possible avaliable  month i.e $12$

> $$\binom{7}{3}*12$$

and then rest $4$ people the rest a possible avaliable  month i.e $11$

which makes the total of

> $$\binom{7}{3}*12*11^{4}$$

We have overcounted many thing in case of remaining $4$ unselected people from a

group of $7$

$\Rightarrow$ it may be the case that all $4$ people may have birthday in same month.

Possible ways =

> $$\binom{4}{4}*11$$

$\Rightarrow$ it may be the case that all $3$ out of $4$ people may have birthday in same month.

possible ways=

> $$\binom{4}{3}*11*10$$

total overcount=

> $$\binom{4}{4}*11+\binom{4}{3}*11*10$$

Required numerator=

> $$\binom{7}{3}*12*11^{4}-\binom{4}{4}*11-\binom{4}{3}*11*10$$

Required probablity=

> $$\frac{\binom{7}{3}*12*11^{4}-\binom{4}{4}*11-\binom{4}{3}*11*10}{12^{7}}$$

Am i correct ?

I have confusion that do we need to subtract $2$ person having birthday on same month whle considering the overcounting .

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that each month may occur with equal probability for a given person's birthday?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes!

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Does it mean "the largest number of people sharing the same birthmonth is three, and there is exactly one such group of three people" (i.e. excluding a birthmonth shared by four people)? It seems that this is the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counts $\binom44×11$ and $\binom43×11×10$ are only valid if the *intended* group of three is fixed. To account for all possible intended groups they need to be multiplied by $12×\binom73$.

Then again, there is a subtle error in the count of the 3-3-1 groupings: either of the two 3-groups may be selected first. Therefore, the amended count $12×\binom73×11×\binom43×10$ needs to be divided by two – each possible selection for the months is counted twice here.

The correct final probability is
$$\frac{12×\binom73×11^4-12×\binom73×11×\binom44-\frac12(12×\binom73×11×\binom43×10)}{12^7}$$

Comment: @laura If you are interested in the approximate probability, it is roughly 0.17 according to Wolfram Alpha (http://bit.ly/2qS1G39)